# Understanding the constraint of SVM optimization problem

Tags: geometry, convex-optimization, machine-learning

I'm learning SVM (support vector machines) from [this book](https://www.svm-tutorial.com/). I understand formulations of functional and geometric margins, it's also clear that we want to maximize geometric margin in order to find the optimal hyperplane, which separates the data points optimally.

What I don't understand is the constraint of the optimization problem. Following problem is given in the mentioned book:

$$\max_{w, b} M$$
$$s.t. \gamma_{i} >= M, i = 1,2...m$$

Where $M$ is the geometric margin of the hyperplane and $\gamma_i$ is geometric margin of a single data point $(x_i, y_i)$. Which is given by:

$$\gamma_i = y_i \left(\frac{w \cdot x_i}{||w||} + \frac{b}{||w||}\right) $$

Why we need this constraint? Couldn't we solve the problem without this constraint? I don't find an intuitive reason behind the constraint.

Answer (score 1):

I must say that I am more familiar with a different constraint, which basically gives similar results. First note that, in this version, you have a hard margin SVM which means that there will be no misclassification nor uncertainty. Thus every point must not be inside the margin nor on the "wrong side" of the margin.

The constraint itself, serves to obtain a solution as much general as it can be, so that there the error on the test data will be as small as possible, i.e. the larger the margin the higher the chance of getting less misclassification.

Hope it helped. Feel free to discuss this much further.

Comment: Yes you're right. But the constraint does not make intuitive sense to me. I don't understand why this particular constraint we need to solve the SVM problem?

Comment: If you find any hyperplane where each point is correctly classified, then it is still a solution to SVM, yet the solution itself is not generalized enough. Note that the constraint itself states that the distance between any point and the separating hyperplane is at least the margin thus, it's correctly classified since 1. because of the constraint on the distance, and 2. since constraint holds only when the point is correctly classified (otherwise u will have $\gamma_i  \geq M$ but $\gamma_i < 0$). Note that $M > 0$.